# Save image file with dialog using java

Tags: java, image, dialog, save

does anyone know how to save a file image with previously
show a dialog to choose where the location is and input a name of the file?

thanks for your response, appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify a technology, with swing you can use JFileChooserDialog, see [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more info.

```
JFileChooserDialog fcd = new JFileChooserDialog();
fcd.showSaveDialog(component);
```